# How to retrieve content from local site to live wordpress site using wp rest api

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, api

I have been trying to use the wp rest api to pull data from local site to live wordpress site using shortcode. When I try to do the reverse that is to pull posts from live to local it works but when i change links to retrieve from local to live it does not display anything on the page.

I already have the wp rest api installed on both sites. Below is my code:

```
function my_recent_posts_shortcode($atts){
 $response = wp_remote_get( 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts' );
  if( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
 return;
 }

 $posts = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );
 if( empty( $posts ) ) {
 return;
 }

if( !empty( $posts ) ) {
$list = '<ul class="recent-posts">';

foreach( $posts as $post ) {
$list .='<li><a href="' . $post->link. '">' . $post->title->rendered . '</a>
</li>';
}
return $list . '</ul>';
}
}
add_shortcode('recent-posts', 'my_recent_posts_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because "localhost" isn't a valid host name -- you have to access the posts via your public IP address.

Type in "whats my IP" into any search engine, and it will give you a series of 4 numbers separated by dots,

example:   `124.98.221.75`

Then, replace the word `localhost` with  `124.98.221.75`

So it will be

`$response = wp_remote_get( 'http://124.98.221.75/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts' );`

Comment: let me try that

Comment: It does not work i had also tried to get the posts of the site itself like this wp_remote_get( 'http://domain.com/new/wp-json/wp/v2/posts' ); and it still did not work where domain.com is the name of the live site. But when i do same for localhost on local site it atleast fetches the posts of the local site and displays using shortcode on local site

Comment: That might be due to the setup of the live site --- its possible that it has wp_remote_get()  disabled for security

Comment: @Landry wp_remote_get( 'domain.com/new/wp-json/wp/v2/posts'; );  remove semicolon in breket

Answer (score 0):

you can add ?page={$page_number} to the URL that you're requesting.

for example, http://domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?page=2.

Comment: please can you help me with another question on this link;

Comment: @ VasimVanzara  this is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40929020/post-request-to-custom-end-point

Comment: ok let me check,if this question is complete please mark complete.It helpful to someone.

Comment: I marked thisquestion complete not because it answered my question entirely but because it gave me a clue on when  to use and when localhost and  local ip.

Comment: If problem solve or you find solution its better to improve answer by edit existing answer.