# Post request to custom end point

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-api, wordpress-rest-api

I wish to make a post request to a remote site but so that it updates remote site with data from database. I succeeded in getting the data using get request from database of current site but am unable to create a callback function for the post request. This is my code

```
function register_custom_route(){

register_rest_route( 'silentblast-dashboard/v1', '/getsetting/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
        array(
            'methods' => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'retrieve_settings_data',
            ),

        array(
            'methods' => 'POST',
            'callback' => 'update_settings_data',
            )
            ));
}

function retrieve_settings_data(){

$out = get_option( 'buddysettings');

return $out;

}

function update_settings_data( $posts ){

//How to build this code to make post requests to remote site

}
```

Comment: are you edit something??

Comment: @VasimVanzara, i don't understand your question

Comment: I mean your code is not here for retrive

Comment: @VasimVanzara register_rest_route( 'silentblast-dashboard/v1', '/getsetting/(?P\d+)', array( array( 'methods' => 'GET', 'callback' => 'retrieve_settings_data', ),    array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'update_settings_data',
        )
        ));    }

function retrieve_settings_data(){

$out = get_option( 'buddysettings');

return $out;

}

function update_settings_data( $posts ){

//How to build this code to make post requests to remote site

}

Comment: @VasimVanzara,  the post has been edited above check now

Comment: @BartBergmans can you help too

Comment: are you asking for update setting code??

Comment: @VasimVanzara, Yes

Comment: Sorry,can't code please try something if you stuck then we will.

Comment: If you can't help, @VasimVanzara, then don't comment at all ^^